# View not being updated using LiveData, a TimerTask and Retrofit

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have to make a GET request every second and I have to update the UI with the incoming fresh data.

I managed to get the repeating network request working using a `Timer`. I can see `okhttp` logs showing the repeating responses with fresh data each second.

However, the UI is not updating with the new data. It only shows the data from the first request. I have tried to implement MVVM calling the network and returning a `LiveData` to be observed in the fragment.

**Edit**: I just noticed the new data is being appended to the list as the `recyclerview` now is growing and growing every second with new items.

**ViewModel**

```
class RatesViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _rates = MutableLiveData<RatesResponse>()

    val rates : LiveData<RatesResponse>
        get() = _rates

    fun init(base: String) {
        timer("NetworkRequest",false, 0, 1000) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                _rates.postValue(RatesRepository().getRates(base))

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(RatesViewModel::class.java)

viewModel.init("EUR")

    val ratesLiveData = viewModel.rates

    ratesLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
        addElements(response.rates)

        if (ratesAdapter == null) {
            setUpRecyclerView()
        } else {
            ratesAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
    })

    setUpRecyclerView()
}
```

**Add element function**

```
private fun addElements(allRates: Rates) {
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "EUR", "Euro", R.drawable.eur, 1.00))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "AUD", "Australian Dollar", R.drawable.aud, allRates.AUD))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "BGN", "Bulgarian Lev", R.drawable.bgn, allRates.BGN))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "BRL", "Brazilian Real", R.drawable.brl, allRates.BRL))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "CAD", "Canadian Dollar", R.drawable.cad, allRates.CAD))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "CHF", "Swiss franc", R.drawable.chf, allRates.CHF))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "CNY", "Chinese Yuan", R.drawable.cny, allRates.CNY))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "CZK", "Czech Koruna", R.drawable.czk, allRates.CZK))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "DKK", "Danish Krone", R.drawable.dkk, allRates.DKK))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "GBP", "British Pound", R.drawable.gbp, allRates.GBP))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "HKD", "Hong Kong Dollar", R.drawable.hkd, allRates.HKD))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "HRK", "Croatian Kuna", R.drawable.hrk, allRates.HRK))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "HUF", "Hungarian Forint", R.drawable.huf, allRates.HUF))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "IDR", "Indonesian Rupiah", R.drawable.idr, allRates.IDR))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "ILS", "Israeli Shekel", R.drawable.ils, allRates.ILS))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "INR", "Indian Rupee", R.drawable.eur, allRates.INR))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "ISK", "Icelandic Króna", R.drawable.isk, allRates.ISK))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "JPY", "Japanese Yen", R.drawable.jpy, allRates.JPY))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "KRW", "South Korean Won", R.drawable.krw, allRates.KRW))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "MXN", "Mexican Peso", R.drawable.mxn, allRates.MXN))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "MYR", "Malaysian Ringgit", R.drawable.myr, allRates.MYR))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "NOK", "Norwegian Krone", R.drawable.nok, allRates.NOK))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "NZD", "Bulgarian Lev", R.drawable.bgn, allRates.BGN))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "PHP", "Philippine Peso", R.drawable.php, allRates.PHP))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "PLN", "Polish Złoty", R.drawable.pln, allRates.PLN))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "RON", "Romanian Leu", R.drawable.ron, allRates.RON))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "RUB", "Russian Rouble", R.drawable.rub, allRates.RUB))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "SEK", "Swedish krona", R.drawable.sek, allRates.SEK))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "SGD", "Singapore Dollar", R.drawable.sgd, allRates.SGD))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "THB", "Thai Baht", R.drawable.thb, allRates.THB))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "USD", "United States Dollar", R.drawable.usd, allRates.USD))
        ratesList.add(Currency(
            "ZAR", "South African Rand", R.drawable.zar, allRates.ZAR))
    }
```

Comment: what is AddElements() doing? please attach that or add a link to your repo.

Comment: viewModelScope.launch{ timer("NetworkRequest",false, 0, 1000 { _rates.postValue(RatesRepository().getRates(base)) } }

Comment: @karandhillon https://github.com/JoseGbel/rev-example thank you! I edited the question I noticed something new that is happening.I have explained it above.

Comment: @saurabh1489 I tried that already and I get a complie error:                 Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body

Answer (score 1):

Did some formatting to separate different parts of logic

### VIEWMODEL

```
class RatesViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _rates = MutableLiveData<RatesResponse>()
    val rates : LiveData<RatesResponse>
        get() = _rates

    fun setupTimer(zone: String) = viewModelScope.launch { 
        timer("NetworkRequest",false, 0, 1000) { 
            val latestRates = getRates(zone)
            _rates.postValue(latestRates) 
            } 
        }

    suspend fun getRates(zone: String) = RatesRepository().getRates(zone)
}
```

### FRAGMENT

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(RatesViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.setupTimer("EUR")
    val ratesLiveData = viewModel.rates

    ratesLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
        addElements(response.rates)
    })

    /**
    * Your recyclerView should not get setup again and again anytime a new value is posted in the livedata.
    */

    if (ratesAdapter == null) setUpRecyclerView()
    else ratesAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

You mentioned that the new data is getting appended at the end of the list i.e. **`allRates`**, in that case instead of **`ADD`** use **`UPDATE`**, as ADD will not remove the old elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it does not work when extracting  "if (ratesAdapter == null) setUpRecyclerView()
    else ratesAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()" outside the observer. Any idea why?

Comment: What you want is your dataSet which is being fetched to the recyclerView's Adapter to observe the LiveData. If you want to do some modifications on the LiveData then use Transformations on it.

What you are doing right now is getting the liveData, modifying it in your addElements()  method. Instead do that modifications in the ViewModel. Your Activity should only be used as container. Watch this video and you will understand https://youtu.be/2rO4r-JOQtA?t=364

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot certainly. However, I can't see a way of transforming an object that has many float fields into a list where each element is one of those float fields in the object. I have seen ways of transforming a list into another list, but no an object into a list. Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by calling the `clear()` method on the list at start of the `addElemenet()` function.

I don't think this is the right thing to do, though.